# How to Bind Data in xaml using C# from sqlserver

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I bind data in xaml? I'm using the following logic:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mahendra;Initial Catalog=Win8App;User ID=sa;Password=*******");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Registration", conn);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
conn.Close();
```

My basic need is to show the same data as the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to execute the command. The DataAdapter do it for you (in the 'Fill' method). To show your result you can use your DataTable as a source and set the Autopopulate colums to true in your DataGrid. I think you don't need the DataSet.

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense to use some ORM software rather than direct usage of SqlConnection/SqlCommand, which are, by the way, not disposed in your code. Consider reading this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340709.aspx , there is an example on data-binding in WPF using Entity Framework.